# Reference Error when dynamically creating variables with eval() in Angular

Tags: angularjs, eval, referenceerror, dynamic-variables

I am trying to create dynamically generated variables based on another variable, such as:

```
var limit = 2;
$scope.blank_item = [];
$scope.create_vars = function(limit){
  for(i=0; i<limit; i++){
    eval('var item' + i) = $scope.blank_item;
  };
};
```

And this should give me 3 new variables like below:

```
var item0 = [];
var item1 = [];
var item2 = [];
```

However, when I try to do this, I get the following error message:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Angular. The value passed to `eval()` has to be one or more statements, not part of a statement. And you certainly can't pass part of a statement to `eval()` and then assign a value to it.

Even you could do that, it would just be creating temporary variables that disappeared as soon as your function finished executing.

Ditch the `eval()` and use an array:

```
var limit = 2;
var items = [];
$scope.blank_item = [];
$scope.create_vars = function(limit){
  for(i=0; i<limit; i++){
    items[i] = [];
  };
};
```

Comment: Wow thats perfect! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you! :)